What if a fielder touches or crosses the boundary rope while the ball is still in the air and eventually he takes the catch? Will that be out or six?
What would be the decision? Because he didn't do that intentionally and he comes in the field and takes the catch inside the boundary fairly?

The answer here depends on exactly where and when the fielder touches the ball and where and when they touch the ground. I could just write out Law 19.5.2 but I'm not sure that's going to be very insightful - could you edit your question to include the specific circumstances you are interested in?

He touched the outside part of boundary before touching the ball and when he caught the ball he was already back inside the rope .hope you understood now
